# How can I create a JavaScript object constructor in a module?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a reusable javascript object (I want to use new). When I attempt to new up one of my custom objects I get an error:

> "org.myorg.sadp.section.sadpSection is not a constructor"

I am modularizing my JS for namespace reasons. I wonder if that is the problem:

```
if (!window.org) var org = { myorg: {} };    
if (!org.myorg) org["myorg"] = { sadp: {} };
if (!org.myorg.sadp) org.myorg["sadp"] = {};

org.myorg.sadp.section = (function(ns) {
    if (ns.section) {
        return ns;
    }
    else {
        ns.section = {};
    }
    ns.section.sadpSection = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isCompleted = false;
        this.booleanQuestions = new Array();
        this.multipleChoiceQuestions = new Array();
        this.sliders = new Array();
        return true;
    }
    return ns;

} (org.myorg.sadp))
```

This results in the error:

```
var myObj = new  org.myorg.sadp.section.sadpSection("test");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically making `org.myorg.sadp.section` equal `org.myorg.sadp`.  This isn't want you want, and it's basically infinite recursion:

```
org.myorg.sadp.section == org.myorg.sadp.section.section
```

and the same is true no matter how many `.section`s you add.  You can change it to:

```
org.myorg.sadp.section = 
{
    sadpSection: function(name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.isCompleted = false;
        this.booleanQuestions = new Array();
        this.multipleChoiceQuestions = new Array();
        this.sliders = new Array();
    }
}
```

You can add a:

```
if(!org.myorg.sadp.section.sadpSection)
```

to avoid reassigning the constructor.

That isn't any less modular.  The return true is also unnecessary.

Comment: That is to say remove `.section` from the line `org.myorg.sadp.section = (function(ns)` and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a [namespace library](https://github.com/webspinner/nsjs) for handling this type of module system you may want to check out. The idea is that you would use it like this:

```
ns('org.myorg.sadp.section');

org.myorg.sadp.section.load('sadpSection', function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.isCompleted = false;
    // always better to use array literals than constructor
    this.booleanQuestions = []; 
    this.multipleChoiceQuestions = [];
    this.sliders = [];
    return true;
});
```

but basically the problem you are dealing with is that you are returning `ns` instead of `section`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this bit here:

```
org.myorg.sadp.section = (function(ns) {
```

It should be:

```
org.myorg.sadp = (function(ns) {
```